# Dense layer probably produces InvalidArgumentError: Incompatible shapes: [0,2] vs. [32,2]

Tags: python, azure, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

**The setup**

I am using Python 3.6, TF 2.4.0
on an Azure DSVM  STANDARD_NC6 (6 Cores, 56 GB RAM, 380 GB Disk) using 1 GPU

---

**The parameters/model**

I have training data: `print(xtrain.shape)` with shape `(4599, 124, 124, 3)`
and ytrain | yval as categorical.

I use a classic generator

```
datagen = ImageDataGenerator(
    zoom_range=0.1,
    rotation_range=25,
    width_shift_range=0.1,
    height_shift_range=0.1,
    shear_range=0.15,
    horizontal_flip=True,
    fill_mode="nearest"
    )

datagen.fit(xtrain)
```

And my model is the base mobilenetv2 with own head:

```
baseModel = MobileNetV2(weights="imagenet", 
                        include_top=False, 
                        input_tensor=Input(shape=(224, 224,3)), 
                        #input_shape=(224, 224, 3),
                        )

headModel = baseModel.output
headModel = AveragePooling2D(pool_size=(7, 7))(headModel)
headModel = Flatten(name="flatten")(headModel)
headModel = Dense(64, activation="relu")(headModel)
headModel = Dropout(0.5)(headModel)
headModel = Dense(2, activation="softmax")(headModel)

model = Model(inputs=baseModel.input, outputs=headModel)

for layer in baseModel.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

model.compile(loss="mse", optimizer='adam', metrics=["accuracy"])
```

When I now fit the model

```
Batch_Size=1

h = model.fit(
datagen.flow(xtrain, ytrain, batch_size=Batch_Size),
steps_per_epoch=len(xtrain) // Batch_Size,
validation_data=(xval, yval),
validation_steps=len(xval) // Batch_Size,
epochs=EPOCHS,
callbacks=[model_checkpoint_callback, Board])
```

---

**The Error**

I get errors (all same but changing with batch size and loss function)

When I use `batch_size=1` with `loss=mse`, `categorical_crossentropy`, or others, the model trains but throws following error at the epoch end

> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_2: expected
> **shape=(None, 224, 224, 3), found shape=(1, 124, 124, 3)**

If I I use a `batch_size` above 1, e.g., 32 with `loss=categorical_crossentropy` the error is thrown befor training:

> InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: **[32] vs. [0]**   [[node
> Equal (defined at :12) ]]
> [Op:__inference_train_function_65107]

with `loss=mse`

> InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: **[0,2] vs. [32,2]**   [[node
> gradient_tape/mean_squared_error/BroadcastGradientArgs (defined at
> :12) ]]
> [Op:__inference_train_function_81958]

If I change the Hidden units of the last Dense Layer, the error changes to that. e.g.

```
...
headModel = Dense(5, activation="softmax")(headModel)
```

results in

> InvalidArgumentError:  Incompatible shapes: **[0,5] vs. [32,2]**

**Apparently the correct input shape gets lost somwhere. Especially the batch size (second dimension is based on dense hidden units). Does anyone have an idea?
thanks**

I checked many answeres from this old thread on git : https://github.com/kuza55/keras-extras/issues/7
but could not find a solution there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data you are feeding to the network must have the same shape than the input of the network. You are trying to feed a network that accept an image of dimensions `224x224x3` with data that has dimensions `124x124x3`.

You can either:

- load the mobilenet network with a compatible input dimension

  ```
  baseModel = MobileNetV2(weights=None, 
                    include_top=False, 
                    input_tensor=Input(shape=(124, 124,3)), 
                    )
  ```

  This approach has the downside of not being able to use pretrained weights.
- reshape your input data to the size of the input of the model. In that case, resizing your `124xx124` images to `224x224`. There is plenty of way to do it, but if you are willing to keep `ImageDataGenerator`, I suggest doing it before hand.

Comment: Dear Lord... please send me increased eye-sight next time. 
Thanks so much. I spend all night yesterday trying to figure that our. Sometims you just need another fresh pair of eyes. Have a save and happy life.